# How can I animate a python pcolormesh using an existing 3D array where the third axis is the time steps?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jquery-animate

I create a pcolormesh for the 2D diffusion equation creating a 3D array of x, y and t. A static 2D plot for a specific t is straightforward. How can I animate it over all the time steps?

I create my 3D array using the following:

```
set array for x and y
grid_size = 100
t_iter = 1000

D = .01
length = 1.0
tmax = 1.0

dx = dy = length/grid_size
dt = tmax/t_iter

rho = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size, t_iter))
#rho[:] = 1.2
rho[grid_size//2, grid_size//2, 0] = 1.2  # set the initial configuration

for n in range(t_iter-1):
    for j in range(grid_size-1):
        for i in range(grid_size-1):
            pxx = rho[i+1,j,n] + rho[i-1,j,n] - 2*rho[i,j,n]
            pyy = rho[i,j+1,n] + rho[i,j-1,n] - 2*rho[i,j,n]
            rho[i,j,n+1] = D*dt*(pxx/dx**2+pyy/dy**2)
```

I can plot the data using pcolormesh (without the labels and stuff) for specific values of t:

```
plt.pcolormesh(rho[:,:,500])
```

[image: Color mesh for t = 500]

I tried this, but it doesn't "animate" anything. What am I missing?

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

mesh = ax.pcolormesh(rho[:,:,0])

def animate(i):
    ax.pcolormesh(rho[:,:,i])
    
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10, frames=t_iter-1, repeat=False)

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image: Animation attempt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things are going wrong:

- In `animate()`, the mesh should be updated. `mesh.set_array()` sets new values. As the internal data structure needs a 1D array, the 2D array should be "raveled": `mesh.set_array(rho[:, :, i].ravel())`.
- `animate()` should return a list of the changed elements. The trailing comma in `return mesh,` is Python's way to make a "tuple" of just one element.
- The most tricky problem here, is that preferably all images use the same color mapping. `vmin` tells which value maps to the "lowest" color (dark purple in the default viridis map), while `vmax` corresponds to the value for the "highest" color (yellow in viridis). If they are net set explicitly, matplotlib will calculate them as the minimum and maximum of the **first** image, `0` and `1.2` in this case. These values don't go well for the other images. Usually, the overall minimum and maximum give suitable values. But, in this case, the "interesting" part of the image is in a much narrower range. I experimented using the 1st and 99th percentiles, which seem to work well, but you'll probably want to adapt these values.

The updated code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

grid_size = 100
t_iter = 1000

D = .01
length = 1.0
tmax = 1.0

dx = dy = length / grid_size
dt = tmax / t_iter

rho = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size, t_iter))
# rho[:] = 1.2
rho[grid_size // 2, grid_size // 2, 0] = 1.2  # set the initial configuration

for n in range(t_iter - 1):
    for j in range(grid_size - 1):
        for i in range(grid_size - 1):
            pxx = rho[i + 1, j, n] + rho[i - 1, j, n] - 2 * rho[i, j, n]
            pyy = rho[i, j + 1, n] + rho[i, j - 1, n] - 2 * rho[i, j, n]
            rho[i, j, n + 1] = D * dt * (pxx / dx ** 2 + pyy / dy ** 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

mesh = ax.pcolormesh(rho[:, :, 0], vmin=np.percentile(rho.ravel(), 1), vmax=np.percentile(rho.ravel(), 99))

def animate(i):
    mesh.set_array(rho[:, :, i].ravel())
    return mesh,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10, frames=t_iter, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help deciphering the animation codes. Still, nothing is animated. All I get is a static frame of the initial colormesh.

Comment: I'm running this in an PyCharm environment, where it does produce an animation. If you are using Jupyter, you might need something like `%matplotlib widget` or `%matplotlib qt` to have a non-static matplotlib window. Do the [tutorial examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html) work in your environment?

Comment: I'm running a Jupyter notebook environment. After updating the conda packages everything works. Thank you. I even added a colorbar for reference.